# Is it possible $\sin\alpha=\cos\alpha=1?$

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible $\sin\alpha=\cos\alpha=1?$

We have defined trigonometry using a unit circle. The point $X(1;1)$ does not lie on the trig circle, right? Does this mean that $\alpha$ does not exist?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: it would contradict $\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha=1$

Comment: You can also see that it doesn't exist, thanks to the identity $\cos^2\alpha + \sin^2\alpha = 1$. If what you say above was possible, you would have $1=2$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I saw the question but I don't think I understand it.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, thank you for the response! I got it. But what if we have $\sin\alpha=\cos\alpha=\dfrac{\sqrt2}{2}?$ Does $\alpha$ exist then? I checked and the identity $\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha=1$ holds. Does this mean that $\alpha$ exist? Is this a sufficient condition for $\alpha$ to exist?

Comment: Yes, $\sin(\pi/4)=\cos(\pi/4)=\dfrac{\sqrt2}2$, and there also exists $\theta$ such that $\sin(\theta)=\cos(\theta)=\dfrac{-\sqrt2}2$

Comment: Yes, but in case I don't know the exact values of the trig functions for the table angles, if I see that the mentioned identity holds, can I say that the angle exists? If $\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha=1$, then $\alpha$ exists for sure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sin ^2 x + \cos ^2 x = 1$ for all $x$, so if you had $\cos \alpha = \sin \alpha = 1$, then $\sin ^2 \alpha + \cos ^2 \alpha$ would be equal to $2$. This is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you already gave is the clearest in my opinion. The trigonometric functions can be defined using the unit circle, so that $\sin(\theta)$ represents the $y$-coordinate when you have travelled $\theta$ degrees/radians anticlockwise around the unit circle, starting from the point $(1,0)$. Likewise, $\cos(\theta)$ represents the $x$-coordinate when you have travelled $\theta$ degrees/radians around.

Since the equation of a unit circle is $x^2+y^2=1$, and $(x,y)=(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$, we obtain the identity
$$
\cos(\theta)^2+\sin(\theta)^2=1 \, ,
$$
which math's answer references. This is one way to answer your question. More directly, we know that the point $(1,1)$ does not lie on the unit circle, since the distance from the origin to that point is $\sqrt{2}$. Hence, it is never true that $\sin(\theta)=\cos(\theta)=1$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Is the identity $\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha=1$ a sufficient condition for an angle to exist?

Comment: @KaloyanK. Sine and cosine are defined for all values of $\alpha$, but it is always true that $\sin(\alpha)^2 + \cos(\alpha)^2=1$. Does that answer your question, or am I misunderstanding what you are saying?

Comment: No, you didn't understand what I meant. Let me try again. I mean can we say that if the identity holds, then the angle exists for sure? Are there any cases for which the identity holds but $\alpha$ does not exist... We saw that when $\sin\alpha=\cos\alpha=1$ the identity does not hold, so we conclduded that $\alpha$ does not exist. Can we do it the other way?

Comment: @KaloyanK. It's difficult to understand what you mean, since you say 'if the identity holds...', but the identity *always* holds regardless of what value of $\alpha$ we are talking about. So $\alpha$ could be any one of infinitely many possible values. I am sorry if I am still misunderstanding you; feel free to clarify what you are saying further.

Comment: I'm sorry. English isn't my native language, so that doesn't help. :))But doesn't it hold only if $\alpha$ exists?

Comment: @KaloyanK. What do you mean by if $\alpha$ exists? Could you phrase that in another way, please.

Comment: Well, now I am solving a problem: If $\sin\alpha=\cos\alpha=1,$ does $\alpha$ exist? Is there an angle $\alpha$ for which $\sin\alpha=\cos\alpha=1$ - maybe that's more clear.  Does this help you understand?

Comment: @KaloyanK. Ah, I think I understand. So $\alpha$ doesn't exist if $\sin(\alpha)=\cos(\alpha)=1$. (Although I would prefer saying 'there isn't a value of $\alpha$ such that $\sin(\alpha)=\cos(\alpha)=1$.) $\alpha$ does also not exist if $\sin(\alpha)^2+\cos(\alpha)^2 \neq 1$. Basically, if $x$ is *any* real number, then $\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2=1$.